# Possible to get auto completion for non-prototype object members only?

Tags: autocomplete, ide, pycharm

I have added the momentjs library to my project. When I type `moment().` I get auto completion help from PyCharm. But I get a long list of members, most of which I have no idea what they do.

Is it possible to somehow narrow down that list to only members that are unique for momentjs? As it is now, I have to go to the documentation to find the members I am looking for. As the members are descriptively named, if the auto completion list was shorter, I could find the member I was looking for right there in my IDE instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: You can go to Editor -> General -> Code Completion and check 'Autopopup documentation in (ms): 1000'. That will show documentation right next to your autopopup selection. You should select a 'member' and press 'Alt' + Space (on MAC). At least (if the documentation is available) you don't have to go elsewhere to find what a method does.

Version of PyCharm 5.02 (MAC). I am sure you can find the same option on PC.